# Can't select network in GNOME Settings

Tags: wireless, gnome, network-manager, nmcli

I connected my Wi-Fi when installing Ubuntu and it is still working; I'm using it right now to write this question. After that, I never opened network settings until now.

That said I'm unable to choose another network. The GNOME Wi-Fi settings lists no visible network (not even the one I'm using).

I tried `nmcli` and it is not showing networks as well:

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
```

I think the problem is that `wlo1` is listed as `unavailable`:

```
sudo nmcli d
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
wlo1     wifi      unavailable  --         
docker0  bridge    unmanaged    --         
enp3s0   ethernet  unmanaged    --         
lo       loopback  unmanaged    --
```

This is `nmcli radio` output:

```
sudo nmcli radio
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

I tried `rfkill` with no luck:

```
sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I was able to list available networks with `wpa_cli` so I suppose the device is working properly. How do I make `nmcli` see other networks or how do I make them appear in the gnome settings?

Before you ask, yes, I tried to restart `NetworkManager` and I also rebooted several times after trying solutions from other similar questions that didn't work for me.

#### Edit:

Here are the outputs as requested in comments.

```
sudo cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlo1:
      access-points:
        ASUS_60:
          password: MY_WIFI_PASSWORD
      dhcp4: true
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

```
sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of these terminal commands: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also: `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf ` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network Manager won't manage any interfaces, including your wireless, that are managed in Netplan. If you want the more convenient in a desktop setting, Network Manager to control all interfaces, then replace your netplan files.

It appears that you may have two netplan files. Find out:

```
ls /etc/netplan
```

Rename it or them:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/<name you found>.yaml /etc/netplan/<name you found>.bak
```

Do this for any and all files found.

Next, create a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Add the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing, indentation, etc., so proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x followed by Enter).

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: After reboot everything started working: both `nmcli` and GNOME Wi-Fi GUI,